# Interpreting the parameters of VAR model

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression

If I have 26 parameters (coefficients) estimated in my VAR model, how can I interpret them?Is possible? Or I should consider only the results of IRF and Granger - causality test?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It is indeed difficult to interpret jointly the effect of several lags. This is precisely why IRFs are such useful summaries of the VAR's coefficients

Comment: Thank you so much.Can I ask you something else please: and the restricted VAR?I have many coefficients on the restricted VAR, too?